# How to make mint sauce

Tags: sauce, mint

I seem to have the basic ingredients. Mint (from the garden), sugar, vinegar. However I seem to end up with vinegary mint, or minty vinegar depending on the relative quantities.

From a jar, it seems a lot richer in flavour and more sauce like. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Never heard of making a mint sauce with mint, sugar and vinegar. I usually just use mint and yogurt when I want a mint sauce. I take my fresh mint and chop it very finely. Then I whip it in a bowl with fresh whole milk yogurt. I spend a solid several minutes whipping it. Works very well for me.

Is there a specific vinegar and mint recipe you're working from?

Comment: It is a British accompaniment to lamb, goes very well. I didn’t realise it was a local thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be saying you have two issues: weak flavor, and watery sauce. There can be many separate causes for each, but one problem that causes both issues is a lack of reduction.

What are you doing to reduce the sauce down and concentrate it? 
Are those the only 3 ingredients you are using?

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head. I was just mushing it together, I didn't realise it needed reducing. I'll try next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using honey instead of sugar.  It is obviously more congealed and might hold the ingredients together well.  I'd try that before reducing, although the honey mixture might be best warmed.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds to me like your trying to make a mint jelly, not a sauce, only your missing one of the main ingredients and that is pectin......I like to make the jalapeno mint jelly   :)

Grandma Abby

Comment: If the OP says they want sauce, I doubt that they want jelly.